# Show that $4$ does not divide $12x+3$ for any $x$ in the integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm not exactly sure where to start on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Show that $4$ does not divide $12x+3$ for any $x$ in the integers.

Here's what I have so far:

There exist c in the integers such that 4 | 12x+3. Then 12x+3 = 4y for some y in the integers. This is a contradiction since y = 3x + 3/4 and y is in the integers.

Is that correct?

Comment: If $n$ divides $m$ and $n$ divides $0 \leq k \leq m$, does $n$ necessarily divide $m - k$?

Comment: @Bruce: Care to clarify? I'm not sure (off the top of my head) what it means for an integer to divide an inequality....

Comment: Yes, I meant $n \mid k$ with $0 \leq k \leq m$.

Comment: Does my edit make sense now? I added what I believed to be correct based off of hints. @CameronBuie

Comment: @Slae: Your original question didn't confuse me. I was merely suggesting to Bruce that he clarify his comment for you.

Comment: $12x+3=12x+4-1$ which is not divisible by $4$ for any $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A number which is divisible by $4$ is **always even** where as $12x+3$ is always **Odd**.

Comment: I dont think I'm trying to show that it's even or odd. I think I'm trying to see if the result will leave me with an integer. Right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Slae Suppose $4\mid x$ then $x$ has to be first of all even. Now since $12x+3$ is odd for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $4\nmid (12x+3)$ and so cannot be an integer.

Comment: Ah. I see. Is my answer technically correct above as well? I get that your stating that they contradict each other since one has to be odd and the other even, but can I contradict it by stating that y is not in the integers as well? I'm new to this so I'm not sure which would be more appropriate and/or best.

Comment: @Slae Yeah your answer looks good :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of hints:

1. Any time you want to prove something for all integers a good thing to try would be induction (proving that the truth for $k<n$ implies the truth for $n$).
2. Remember that if a number divides $a$ and $b$ then it should divide $a+b$ as well.

Comment: Induction *should* be totally unnecessary, here.

Comment: Thanks I missed typing "all"

Comment: So since it doesn't divide a + b then this is a proof by contradiction correct? **see edit**

Comment: That is definitely the structure for the proof I had in mind, it looks like you have the basic structure down based on your edit but you might want to think of how to make your argument easier to follow. Like Cameron said you don't actually need induction here (it is just what i thought of using).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $12x + 3$ is always odd.

To be divisible by $4$ means to contain at least two factors of $2$.

Odd numbers contain no factors of $2$ so $12x + 3$ can never be divisible by $4$

Answer (score 0):

Saying $4 | 12x + 3$ is equivalent to saying there exists an integer $k$ such that $4k = 12x + 3$.

If this is the case, then also $4k - 12x = 3$, or $4(k - 3x) = 3$.  $4 \cdot 0 = 0$ and $4 \cdot 1 = 4$, so this would imply $0 < k - 3x < 1$, which is impossible.  So it must not be the case that $4 | 12x + 3$.